# Java - Most efficient matching method

Tags: java, performance, list, matching

Assuming one needs to store a list of items, but it can be stored in any variable type; what would be the most efficient type, if used mostly for matching?

To clarify, a list of items needs to be contained, but the form it's contained in doesn't matter (enum, list, hashmap, Arraylist, etc..)
This list of items would be matched against on a regular basis, but not edited. What would the most efficient storage method be, assuming you only need to write to the list once, but could be matching multiple times per second?

Note: No multi-threading

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "matched"? You need to determine whether a given item is present in the set?

Comment: You want something with the lowest read time complexity. `HashMap` has `O(1)` complexity, which is about as low as it gets.

Comment: Yeah basically the idea is to determine whether an item in the set is contained in that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashSet` (and `HashMap`) offers `O(1)` complexity. Also note that you should create a *large enough* `HashSet` with small *loadfactor* which means that after a hashcode check the elements in the result bucket will also be found very quickly (in a bucket there is a sequential search). Optimally each bucket should contain 1 element at the most.

You can read more about the concept of capacity and load factor in the Javadoc of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

An even faster solution would be if the number of items is no more than 64 is to create an `Enum` for them and use `EnumSet` or `EnumMap` which stores the elements in a `long` and uses simple and very fast bit operations to test if an element is in the set or map (a contains operation is just a simple bitmask test).

If you choose to go with the `HashSet` and not with the `Enum` approach, know that `HashSet` uses the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of the elements. You might consider overriding them to provide a faster implementation knowing the internals of the items you wish to store.
A trivial optimization of overriding the `hashCode()` can be for example to cache a once computed hash code in the item itself if it doesn't change (and subsequent calls to `hashCode()` should just return the cached value).

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that order doesn't matter. If this is so, use a Set. Java's standard implementation is the HashSet.

Comment: How can you recommend a `HashSet` without knowing what the data item is? What if it can't be hashed? The performance of a hash-based data structure tends towards that of a list when the hashcode implementation gives a poor distribution.

Comment: Everything can be hashed in Java. If the hash code implementation is bad, it tends towards being a List, but won't perform worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient for repeated lookup would almost certainly be an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

> ...  Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if their argument is also an enum set.
>
> ...
>
> Implementation note: All basic operations execute in constant time. They are likely (though not guaranteed) to be **much faster than their HashSet counterparts**. Even bulk operations execute in constant time if their argument is also an enum set.